# Unable to see code coverage for one of my projects

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nunit, code-coverage, opencover

I am not able to see code coverage value to one of my projects.I execute below commands to fetch the same.

For NUnit

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "C:\Example.Tests.dll"  --where "cat == Unit" --result:Example.nunit-result.xml
```

For OpenCover

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe "-target:C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "-targetargs:C:\Example.Tests.dll --where=cat=Unit" -register:XXX
```

I have included `--where=cat=Unit` in Open-cover batch command and I see all my test cases ran successfully but I could not see the code-coverage. What more is missing from my end.

Sonarqube result of my project screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what about the result by **GUI**

Comment: @LeiYang I have added the result of sonarqube

Answer (score 1):

Finally after changing location of results.xml I could see the code coverage.